# Capture SQLPlus like feedback using JDBC

Tags: jdbc

In SQLPlus, the "feedback" by Oracle lets us know the status of the SQL statement executed - like "Created Table ", Table Altered etc (using "SET FEEDBACK ON").

Can such a feedback be captured when SQL statements are run using JDBC ? I am looking more for DDL statements. I am not looking for the output from Prepared Statement methods. I am looking for something directly given by the database - like in SQLPlus.

Purpose : We want to create a job which would run DDL statements. The output is required to show in Audits.

Thanks,
Midhun.

Comment: The approach we took was to integrate log4jdbc into the application. It slows down the application a bit (showed up in the performance testing). But our current version is fine to have it.

Comment: Did you find part of the JDBC API that allows you to get the feedback out?

Comment: Hello - No. I didnt. This is still pending. The only way out is to print the params in Java before we fire the JDBC statement.